# laravel Login view not doing anything

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, controller

I have a laravel project where i need to use multi-auth, so i've changed column names for users table by adding a 'u_' prefix.
For the register, it's all good but whenever i try to login nothing happens and i get redirected back to /login without errors or anything at all.
Here is my

## login.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Login
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                    Forgot Your Password?
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

## User.php Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $primaryKey = "uid";

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'u_username','u_password','u_email','u_first_name','u_last_name','u_country','u_status','u_type',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

and

## loginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function username()
    {
        return 'u_email';
    }
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

It looks like login.blade.php doesn't care about whether i changed `function username() return value` or not, and i haven't really changed anything at all except the fillable array above.

Comment: What about password ? You are saying `really changed anything at all except the fillable` but you changed all login form and their name.

Comment: @C2486 thank you for you reply, but i meant i havent changed something in the routes, middlewares, guards etc..

Comment: I guess it will work if you use `email` and `password` back.

Comment: @C2486 it is useless if i change back to `email` and `password`, but even if i do that it won't work, i don't think that the view is even linked to the controller 'cause nothing is happening at all except refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the modified fields to the fillable array and modifying the username function is not enough. You have to override the **validator** and **create** methods in the **RegisterController** Class. See the Laravel documentation:

> **Validation / Storage Customization**
>
> To modify the form fields that are required when a new user registers with your application, or to customize how new users are stored into your database, you may modify the  **RegisterController** class. This class is responsible for validating and creating new users of your application.
>
> The **validator** method of the RegisterController contains the validation rules for new users of the application. You are free to modify this method as you wish.
>
> The **create** method of the RegisterController is responsible for creating new App\User records in your database using the Eloquent ORM. You are free to modify this method according to the needs of your database.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication?#included-authenticating

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @Femi Nefa for your reply, but i already have done that with registerController, and it works fine, but i have a problem with loginController and login view.

Comment: @Yak0d3 Okay, my bad. Now I see, you also modified the password field name in login.php.blade. If you must do that, then you will have to customize the login guard or authenticate users manually - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication?#authenticating-users

Comment: ive reset login.blade.php to the default contents, but still having the same problem

Comment: @Yak0d3 sounds like you are having problem with your session setup or you got some code mixed up. It is difficult to advice on this without taking a look at the code/setup myself. I hope you figure it out soon. Good luck.